# No ingresar datos duplicados en mysql sin un JTable o JList

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy realizando un sistema clínico en netbeans, y he creado un registro que almacena los datos sin la necesidad de mostrarlos al usuario; estos pueden ser mostrados más adelante, pero requiero saber cómo eliminar la duplicidad de datos en mysql. He visto que muchos lo hacen mediante `JTable` y recorren los datos, pero, como no estoy usando una tabla para recorrer los datos, trato de hacer una consulta previa para eliminar la duplicidad. Mi pregunta es ¿como puedo eliminar datos duplicados sin la necesidad de una `JTable` o `JList`?

Código:

```
public void comparar(String nombre, String paterno,String materno){
    try{
        String SQL = "Select * from datosDoctor where='%"+nombre+"%' and apellidoPaterno='%"+paterno+"'% and apellidoMaterno ='%"+materno+"%'";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL);


boolean existeUsuario = rs.next();
if(existeUsuario){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"El usuario ya existe");
        }else{
            insertarNombre();
        }
}catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error al comparar los datos" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

//método insertarNombre es decir los datos del usuario

```
 public void insertarNombre(){
    try{
       String SQL= "insert into datosDoctor(nomDoctor, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, edad, nacimiento, cedula) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
       PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(SQL);

 pst.setString(1, txtNombre.getText() );
        pst.setString(2, txtPaterno.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtMaterno.getText());
        pst.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText()));
        pst.setString(5, ((JTextField)fechaDoctor.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
        pst.setString(6, txtCedula.getText());
        pst.execute();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Registro guardado");
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No se guardo ningun registro " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

//imagen de la interfaz
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
//los datos nombre apellido paterno y materno, solo deben registrase una vez
//de lo contrario debera mandar un mensaje de "usuario ya registrado"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En primer lugar, el código que muestres debe ir como texto (formateado como código), no como captura de pantalla. En segundo lugar, tu pregunta no tiene mucho sentido; `JTable` y `JList` son elementos de la GUI y no tienen lógica, mientras que el problema de eliminar duplicados no necesita (como bien indicas en la pregunta) interacción con el usuario.

Comment: ¿En el código que has puesto donde se están obteniendo datos duplicados? ¿No puedes obtenerlos sin duplicar directamente en la consulta a base de datos? Incluye información básica de las tablas (CREATE) y un juego básico de los datos con duplicados (INSERT)

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta (enlace Editar bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas) y añade la información que te indican en los otros comentarios. Es posible que el problema esté en tu consulta pero, como puedes ver en LA IMAGEN, no se ve completa (y tampoco sabemos sobre qué datos consultas y qué debería obtenerse... unos datos de prueba serían útiles también). Todo va como texto a menos que realmente se necesite una imagen.

Comment: si, en un rato la corrigo, gracias :D

Comment: ya la edite y agregue datos extras, espero puedan orientarme :D

Comment: Edité tu pregunta: tu IDE (Netbeans) en este caso no tiene nada que ver con lo que preguntás, ya que querés hacerlo _desde **Java**_. Una recomendación: no concatenes los parámetros en tu consulta, ya que se vuelve vulnerable a inyecciones SQL (fijate que en `insertarNombre` sí tenés un `PreparedStatement`, pero en `comparar` los concatenás directamente).

Comment: Esa primera consulta, aparte de las sugerencias que te hacen, tiene mala sintaxis, pues `Select * from datosDoctor where='%"+nombre+"%'` va a resultar en `Select * from datosDoctor where='Juan'` y creo que no es la idea. No te está tirando errores al ejecutar eso? :P

Comment: de echo si, salta directo al catch, pero requiero que lo que se ingrese en la caja de texto, sea comparado con los datos en la base de datos, no se si me doy a entender